# Azure Function with EntityFramework + DI

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

It seems that Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 3.0.4 broke DI with EntityFrameworkCore.

With 3.0.3, I can add an InMemoryDatabase in the DI and use it in my Function, but upgrading to 3.0.4 breaks stating:

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'AzureFunction.Contexts.TestContext' while attempting to activate 'AzureFunction.TestFunction'.

I made the repro project available with picture (see images/) [here](https://github.com/martingemme/azure-function-database)

Comment: Indeed. There's a problem with 3.0.4 which is breaking the DI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60511472/1384539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an issue in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 3.0.4.

You can try it on the [3.0.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/3.0.5) which is released a few hours ago and DI issue is fixed.

Comment: Microsoft.NET.sdk.Functions 3.0.5 released and there are reports it fixes DI problems. @eliashdezr 6 April 01:45 _I can confirm that all the issues related with the dependency injection have been resolved, locally and deployed using the version 3.0.5 of the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package._

Comment: Indeed it - 3.0.5 - fixed it for me.